# Determinant of a square matrix with main diagonal of zeros?

Tags: calculus, matrices, determinant

How can I show that the determinant of a square matrix A of dimension NxN with all elements equal to $-\delta$ except the main diagonal composed by zeros, is equal to $-(N-1)\times \delta^N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is
$$
\mathbf{A} = \delta (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the all-ones vector.

$$
\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{A})
&= \delta^N \det(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T) \\
&= \delta^N \det(1 - \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1}) \\
&= \delta^N (1 - \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1}) \\
&= \delta^N (1 - N) \\
\end{align}
$$

The first equality holds because $\det(\alpha\mathbf{A}) = \alpha^N \det(\mathbf{A})$ for any scalar $\alpha$ and $N$-by-$N$-matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

The second equality is due to Sylvester's determinant identity:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem